# Calculate best estimate of multiple mesurements with known but varying variance

Tags: random-variables, measurement-theory

When multiple experiments measure the same physical quantity and give a set of answers $s={s_1,s_2,...,s_n}$ for $n$ measurement and give an error with different variances $v={v_1,v_2,...,v_n}$. How is the final estimate of $s$ and $v$ calculated ?  The error is assumed to be Gaussian distributed and to be unbiased.

Comment: This looks like data reconciliation.